# Entity Framework Fluent API - Create filtered Index

Tags: sql, .net, database, entity-framework, indexing

I was looking for a way in EF Code FIrst to have an unique index, that allows multiple `NULL` values.

[Here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/allow-nulls-unique-fields/) I found a possible solution by creating an filtered index that will exclude the nulls and only validate the uniqeness of **not** `NULL` values.

The SQL I need to execute is

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indunique 
ON testunique(value) 
WHERE value IS NOT NULL
```

Where `testUnique` is the table, `indunique` index name and `value` the column I want to be unique allowing `NULL` values.

So a way to implement this is by calling `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` in an overrided `Seed()` method of a custom DatabaseInitializer and passing the command above.

**But is there a way to implement this index via Fluent-API or Data-Annotations?**

To implement a unique constraint I use

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transmitter>.HasIndex(t => t.MeasureCellId).IsUnique(True)
```

but how can I implement the filter?

Comment: I almost sure, that you can't create this index via Fluent API or Attributes.

Comment: This is the deafult behavior with EF Core and SQL Server